# unit testing for node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nodeunit

I looked into various frameworks for writing unit tests for an application developed in node.js. There exists multiple options like: nodeunit, jasmine-node, should.js library in Mocha. All seems to be pretty much capable of testing everything. I couldn't find any limitation of any of above mentioned options.

I will prefer to use nodeunit as it seems easy to use as a beginner. Any suggestion about any limitation of nodeunit would be highly helpful before I start working on this. Or any suggestion if anyone thinks that there exists a easier and better option for unit testing in node.js.

Comment: I prefer BDD to TDD, it's easy to read, so I use Mocha and Chai. You can read [this article](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/27/testing-backbone-boilerplate-with-mocha-and-chai/) to get started

Comment: I second @dohaivu 's opinion regarding BDD, but I use Mocha + Should. Both libraries are documented extensively, and provide flexible, read-and-writable tests.

Answer (score 1):

I previously used JUnit in Java and want to find similar testing framework. It was hard for me to getting started with BDD frameworks like Mocha. Finally I stoped on node unit. All advanced functions which I couldn't find in node unit was finded in expect.js. Also important testing framework in web application context is superagent(which helps to make requests, and get responce on tests), it was easy to mix with node unit, and easy to test async code. One more nice thing there is plugin for WebStorm :)